# How to learn queries in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I heartily want to learn about how to build (simple and complex) queries with and without lambda expression in c#.I searched a lot , but perhaps I am may be miss some links to check. can some body tell me where i can learn from basic of Linq ,its all functions, write the queries and all ? please guide me!

Comment: With any Microsoft technology, MSDN should be your first stop :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594

Comment: You can try this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-LINQ-Language-Integrated-Query/dp/1430226536](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-LINQ-Language-Integrated-Query/dp/1430226536)

Comment: Having bought a book and spent some time reading that and the Internet, I agree too - the MSDN tutorial is written by a trainer who wants to explain, rather than a geek who wants to play.

Comment: https://github.com/Basware/LINQ-Tutorial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[101 Linq samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) is a good place to start.

Comment: There is now a more visual version of LINQ samples in ["A Visual Lexicon of LINQ"](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-development/visual-lexicon-linq/)

Answer (score 9):

The [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) is a good place for simple examples.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend http://www.linqpad.net. It's a tool that allows you to easily play with LINQ queries (or any C# code for that matter) and it comes with something like 500 example queries that you can use as starting points.

Answer (score 3):

I've been spending the last several months learning Linq. Here are the resources I have found extremely helpful:

```
Book: Linq in Action - Manning Publications (Jim Wooley)
Book: Linq Pocket Reference - O'Reilly (Albahari)
LinqPad: An absolute must. Very highly Recommended (www.linqpad.net)
Site: 101 Linq Examples (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really great that you are thinking of linq queries..well before moving forward I think you should know the meaning of following terms .

- Deferred and immediate execution

  actually linq works on deferred execution
- Difference `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`

  linq to sql works on `IQueryable` and linq to object work on `IEnumerable`
- Difference between linq to object,linq to sql,linq to dataset,linq to xml
- `ObjectTrackingEnabled` and `DeferredLoadingEnabled`

  these are the very important properties of `DataContext`
- Other ORM like linq to sql

  llblgen pro, nhibernate, ado.net entity frame work

These are the basics of linq.  As soon as you capture all the points, linq will be more interesting.

Comment: Wao, its a nice guideline dude. so many i tried to understand what these terms are, but still it is question mark for me. terms like iEnumerable , Enumerator, Queriable these terms are really confusing me. can you please solve my little question, when we have to use these terms i mean concepts ? if we can itterate list of object then why need of enumerator. i am totally unaware about this.

Comment: well when u r using linq to object,then u shud use iEnumerable,if u r using linq to sql the u shud use Queriable... well some of the predefined collection are based on enumerator mean u cannot jump from onw to another element  just by skiping any element and u even cat go backword,i myself dont like this collection but it is useful where u need traversing of collection

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good book on this to get all the basics. The book is not to thick, and should be quick enough to go through, and perfect for a reference later on.

The book is called [LINQ Pocket Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596519249)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for free LINQ references, check Jon Skeet's brilliant series [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx). He also has an ebook version of the series.

Also check these other links:

[50 LINQ Examples, Tips and How To's](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=727)
[LINQ Secrets Revealed: Chaining and Debugging](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/)

Happy LINQin'! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a quite non-orthodox opinion, but here are couple of great learning materials for comprehending LINQ:

- http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Lecture-Series-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals-Chapter-1

They will lead you straight to LINQ origins and teach how to solve problems in terms of functions composition.

Comment: Links didn't seem relevant or useful.

Comment: So SelectMany doesn't really look like monadic bind and Enumerable methods have nothing common with usual higher-order functions library from almost any FP language? And you look through Erik Meijer lections but didn't see anything about LINQ there? You are right then, these link are irrelevant and useless to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you may find some nice examples in its built-in **[snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx)**:

[image]

*(It already saved me some time, sometimes...)*